# Web2py - How i send email automatically per day?

Tags: python, email, web2py

How I do verification for send one email per day in web2py? I tried using time.sleep(), but It's send a email always when I refresh or got to another page

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use the web2py scheduler. You could define `mail.send` as one of the available tasks, and set the pvars parameter of the task created with `queue_task` to the corresponding parameters of `mail.send` when you want to send a message.

See more details at http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#web2py-Scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Better to use cron to achieve this. You should follow web2py documentation [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Running-tasks-in-the-background).

Comment: I read, but when i try to execute i get some errors:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/guilherme/Documentos/ope/Controle-Estoque/web2py/gluon/shell.py", line 274, in run
    execfile(startfile, _env)
  File "/home/guilherme/Documentos/ope/Controle-Estoque/web2py/gluon/shell.py", line 41, in execfile
    code = compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1013: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Cron is currently not recommended by Massimo.